# Field Operators in PCA GraphQL?

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, dxa2.2, sites-9.5, graphql

We are rewriting our existing CIL client code by replacing it with PCA/GraphQL client code.

To retrieving Dynamic Component Presentations, we are using API method `apiClientProvider.getClient().getComponentPresentations`

With this method call, we want to provide a filter which would retrieve the dynamic components based on the meta data field 'date'.

With CIL, you could build a query criteria as follows:

```
CustomMetaValueCriteria dateCriteria = new CustomMetaValueCriteria(new CustomMetaKeyCriteria("date"),"2022-01-01",  FieldOperator.GREATER_OR_EQUAL_THAN);
```

I was looking was something similar as a field criteria/filter in Java GraphQL Client but I couldn't find it.

Any thoughts how could we achieve this with PCA client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RWS R&D/Support has confirmed that field operators such as '<', '>', 'NotIn', 'Like', etc. are not implemented in the current PCA (GraphQL 9.5/9.6) version.

However, it is planned to be implemented in the next version of Sites 10 (with CRQ-30479).